# Table not listening to value set for foreign key in other table, IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a foreign key in `PropertyChange` table which is `id` in `Run` table. When I run and commit data for both tables I get `IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: PropertyChange.run_id`. From what I read, setting `autoincrement=True` in the `Run` table should have resolved it.

models.py

```
class Run(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Run'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    instance = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    host = Column(String, nullable=False)
    config = Column(JSON, nullable=False)

    property_change = relationship('PropertyChange', back_populates='run')


class PropertyChange(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PropertyChange'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    property_name = Column(String, nullable=True)
    p_values = Column(JSON, nullable=False)
    s_values = Column(JSON, nullable=False)
    c_values = Column(JSON, nullable=True)

    run_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Run.id'), nullable=False)
    run = relationship('Run', back_populates='property_change')
```

Adding and committing data as my data is in dataframe:

```
prod_run = models.Run
prop_change = models.PropertyChanges
pending_data = []
for row in run_df.itertuples():
    pending_data.append(prod_run(instance =row.instance, name=row.name, host =row.host, config = row.config ))
for row in property_changes.itertuples():
    pending_data.append(prop_change(timestamp=row.timestamp, property_name=row.property_name, p_values=row.p_values, s_values=row.s_values, c_values=row.c_values))
session.add_all(pending_data)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Two notes: (1) By default, SQLite does not enforce foreign key constraints. Details [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support). (2) If you already have the data in two separate DataFrames then why bother creating ORM objects and adding them to the session when you can just upload the data directly to the underlying tables? You can always retrieve specific ORM objects after the tables have been updated.

Comment: My question with uploading directly from dataframe is how do I let the `PropertyChange` table know the `run_id` of `Run` table? That's generated after I commit data to `Run` table.

Comment: If you already have the data in two separate DataFrames then they should already have a common key value to link the rows. If you can't use that common (key) value as the primary key for Run (e.g., because it's unique within that subset of rows but not globally unique) then you could at least use it to link the rows within that particular batch.

Comment: I still need to generate globally unique id... which is what I'm stuck on with dataframe.to_sql(). What I think might work and it's super hacky is to commit the Run table first, and then query the db and take the last added row's id and assign that as a column run_id for every row in property_changes dataframe. Then commit that table so it has the correct globally unique id. This is quite a hacky workaround though. Any other ideas?

Comment: That's a common requirement when working with autoincrement (sometimes called "identity") primary keys (PK). The key value doesn't exist until we insert the row, so we have to retrieve it (or have it returned to us) before we can add it as the FK in the child table. SQLAlchemy ORM can actually take care of that for us, but your sample code does not currently tell a new `prop_change` what `prod_run` it belongs to. (I would expect to see `prop_change(timestamp=row.timestamp, … run=someRunObject)`.) In fact, that is the actual reason you are getting the `run_id` NOT NULL constraint violation.

Comment: can you expand on your comment in an answer? I can fix this for the loop approach, but I still don't see a good solution for the dataframe approach.

Comment: I don't know enough about your data to write anything more than a comment-in-answer-form (which is technically "not an answer"). If you fix the ORM approach and post your solution as an answer (it's okay to answer your own question) then if you want to further investigate the DataFrame-to-table option (e.g., if you find that the ORM approach is slow, which it might turn out to be) then you can ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment part is too short to discuss solutions, I will go here:

I will mention some points to check and solve:

`(1)` check the data in your DataFrames related to the columns with `nullable=False`. is there in `nan` values. (`name, host and config` in `run_df` and `timestamp, p_values, s_values` in PropertyChange )

`(2)` Regrading the column 'run_id`in`PropertyChange`, you make it` nullable=False`, and you assigned neither a valid` Run.id`nor a reference to the object of`Run` type.

`(3)` Finally, you make the relation `run = relationship('Run', back_populates='property_change')` in the model `PropertyChange` without a related foreign key in `Run` Model, I faced unexpected problems with SQLalchemy for similar cases.

looking, for either solved or comments :)